# Converting a unirest 'GET' request to axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, next.js

I'm using TheRundown API to get sports data the example they gave me uses unirest, I'm trying to convert that example to an axios request. I got it working for the most part but the problem I'm running into is including the `query` parameters on the axios request.

I have tried using `params` with the axios request but it isn't giving me the extra data in the JSON that I'm asking for.

This is the example code that I'm trying to convert to axios:

```
var unirest = require("unirest");

var req = unirest("GET", "https://therundown-therundown-v1.p.rapidapi.com/sports/3/events");

req.query({
    "include": [
        "all_periods",
        "scores"
    ]
});

req.headers({
    "x-rapidapi-host": "therundown-therundown-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.THERUNDOWN_API_KEY
});


req.end(function (res) {
    if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);

    console.log(res.body);
});
```

This is the code I got so far with axios:

```
response = await axios({
  method: "GET",
  url: `https://therundown-therundown-v1.p.rapidapi.com/sports/1/events`,
  headers: {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "therundown-therundown-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.THERUNDOWN_API_KEY
  },
  params: {
    include: ["all_periods", "scores"]
  }
}).then(
  function(response) {
    sportsData[0].data = response.data;
  }.bind(this)
);
```

So the data that I'm missing from my axios request is the `"score": [Object]` from my axios request. You can see from the JSON data I posted below.

Here is the JSON I get from the unirest `'GET'` request:

```
{ meta: { delta_last_id: '11e9-bc68-68d68d53-8563-74040f62bb04' },
  events:
   [ { event_id: '402cb5659e1cbf08d6f6648fffcd6f91',
       sport_id: 3,
       event_date: '2019-08-11T20:10:00Z',
       rotation_number_away: 927,
       rotation_number_home: 928,
       score: [Object],
       teams: [Array],
       teams_normalized: [Array],
       line_periods: [Object] },
     { event_id: '4cde94df721e1c18bba6389c0f80b34b',
       sport_id: 3,
       event_date: '2019-08-11T23:05:00Z',
       rotation_number_away: 911,
       rotation_number_home: 912,
       score: [Object],
       teams: [Array],
       teams_normalized: [Array],
       line_periods: [Object] },
     { event_id: 'cbfba54a01f82b54dbc4e417cf2e371b',
       sport_id: 3,
       event_date: '2019-08-11T20:10:00Z',
       rotation_number_away: 913,
       rotation_number_home: 914,
       score: [Object],
       teams: [Array],
       teams_normalized: [Array],
       line_periods: [Object] },
     { event_id: 'd2f689438cc61fdebadd464b40247f4a',
       sport_id: 3,
       event_date: '2019-08-11T19:40:00Z',
       rotation_number_away: 909,
       rotation_number_home: 910,
       score: [Object],
       teams: [Array],
       teams_normalized: [Array],
       line_periods: [Object] } ] }
```

Here is the JSON I get from my axios `'GET'` request:

```
{ meta: { delta_last_id: '11e9-bc68-68d68d53-8563-74040f62bb04' },
  events:
   [ { event_id: '402cb5659e1cbf08d6f6648fffcd6f91',
       sport_id: 3,
       event_date: '2019-08-11T20:10:00Z',
       rotation_number_away: 927,
       rotation_number_home: 928,
       teams: [Array],
       teams_normalized: [Array],
       lines: [Object] },
     { event_id: '4cde94df721e1c18bba6389c0f80b34b',
       sport_id: 3,
       event_date: '2019-08-11T23:05:00Z',
       rotation_number_away: 911,
       rotation_number_home: 912,
       teams: [Array],
       teams_normalized: [Array],
       lines: [Object] },
     { event_id: 'cbfba54a01f82b54dbc4e417cf2e371b',
       sport_id: 3,
       event_date: '2019-08-11T20:10:00Z',
       rotation_number_away: 913,
       rotation_number_home: 914,
       teams: [Array],
       teams_normalized: [Array],
       lines: [Object] },
     { event_id: 'd2f689438cc61fdebadd464b40247f4a',
       sport_id: 3,
       event_date: '2019-08-11T19:40:00Z',
       rotation_number_away: 909,
       rotation_number_home: 910,
       teams: [Array],
       teams_normalized: [Array],
       lines: [Object] } ] }
```

Comment: That looks like a correct adaptation. What happens with each version if you manually edit the query parameters into the URL?

Comment: What do API docs show for formatting `include` values?

Comment: I have tried entering the query parameters manually and I get the same response. Unfortunately, there are no docs for this API :(

Comment: I actually solved the problem, I found some details on RapidAPI. All I had to do was ```?include=scores``` to the url. Thanks for the brainstorming, it helped alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios is using `arrayFormat: brackets` by default and that api expects repeated.

The current axios endpoint:

`https://therundown-therundown-v1.p.rapidapi.com/sports/3/events?include[]=all_periods&include[]=scores`

The correct endpoint:

`https://therundown-therundown-v1.p.rapidapi.com/sports/3/events?include=all_periods&include=scores`

You can change this behavior by providing a `paramsSerializer` using the querystring package arrayFormat repeat.

```
var qs = require('qs');

response = await axios({
  method: "GET",
  url: `https://therundown-therundown-v1.p.rapidapi.com/sports/1/events`,
  headers: {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "therundown-therundown-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.THERUNDOWN_API_KEY
  },
  params: {
    include: ["all_periods", "scores"]
  },
  paramsSerializer: function(params) {
       return qs.stringify(params, {arrayFormat: 'repeat'})
  },
}).then(
  function(response) {
    sportsData[0].data = response.data;
  }.bind(this)
);
```